# How to hide activity if it's immediately being redirected

Tags: android

I have a welcome activity that is displayed only if the user is not logged in.
What I do is to start a new activity via intent. (I check, if a user is logged in, then start activity). But, there is a split second where this activity is still visible before the redirection. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You might consider using a custom `DialogFragment` for login. Then when the user logs on successfully allow access to the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

just use the same `Activity` and then inflate either `Fragment` ...the result: zero delay.

this can also be done with method `.setContentView()` and two XML layouts.

there is no point in showing it, while the user has nothing to do there ...

as a rule of thumb: skip all useless complexity (as others suggested).

Comment: Can you please provide a code example? As a beginner I'm having hard time making it work with Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I think use share preference to check user login if it login then shared preference value true and after every start check share preference.

Note: open activity should be start activity check user in start activity if false then redirect welcome screen.

ex. it should be help you

https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

I say use a splash screen. Save the user data in shared preferences and check it in the opening activity. It should be a blank activity with only the shared preferences code and nothing in the xml maybe just a empty layout or space but it should use a `style` where the `android:windowBackground`is your splash screen logo. Window background is sort of a place holder when an activity is being loaded. This way there is always a splash screen logo with no lag. After making the check direct the user to the login activity or the home activity. Dont forget to `finish();` this activity before leaving.

Style:

```
<style name="splash" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_wallpaper</item>
        </style>
```

Apply the theme in Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

As the `splash_wallpaper` may appear different on different screens use drawable xml which defines its gravity.

splash_wallpaper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>

        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/loading"/>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```