# Show Dialog or Activity based on Condition

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I want to show a Dialog or a UI when user first uses the android app. When a condition is satisfied (registration to an application server is done), the UI (or the Dialog) disappears, and a flag is set in SharedPreferences telling that android app is registered so that by each new app start the UI related to registration does not appear.

I do not know what to use since I am beginner in Android development? and which one is better from Performance perspective?
UI Fragments and show/hide fragments based on condition (check SharedPref Flag)? 
Or switch between Activities ? Or is there a UI Intro that can be showed or disabled based on a Flag value?

Comment: see my answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565752/how-to-hide-activity-if-its-immediately-being-redirected/53570330#53570330

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward solution, first you just need to check if there's a flag saved in the prefs. Best to do it in onCreate of your launch activity

```
    val settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val shouldDisplayDialog = settings.getBoolean("first-launch", true)
if(shouldDisplayDialog) // your logic here
```

The second value in method getBoolean is the default one, so it will set value of **shouldDisplayDialog** true if there's no saved value.
After succesfull login or whatever, just write the value to SharedPrefs.

```
with (settings.edit()) {
putBoolean("first-launch", false)
commit()
}
```

That's it!

Comment: thanks for your answer. In fact I know that I will save the Flag and get/update its value in SharedPreferences and I know I will check this in onCreate method of the Activity. But my question was more about what view components to use and how: UI Fragment in same Activity ? or Dialog?  And I need to keep showing the Content of the UI till an event occurs in backend service; so no close or Cancel button should allow the UI to disappear until an event occurs. So my question is which solution is better and performant: Splash Screen? UI Fragments? Switch between activities?

Comment: can it make sence to use DialogFragment and show a dialog based on SharedPref Flag and hide the dialog when a message received from background service?

Comment: in that case, when you are "actively waiting" for the server response...I'd suggest to use a Fragment. Based on my "building good UX" experience, the dialogs should be displayed mainly/only for confirmation action (for example delete item) or for an important information to be displayed. In your case, you need to set the dialog to non cancellable and that blocks most of the unused screen space.
Fragment is a better option IMHO. Also...it provides more flexibility than a regular dialog.

Comment: but...both ways you can achieve the desired effect...this is "just" about how it looks to the user. When there's slow connection, user may end up with some dialog displayed over his screen for a pretty long time. And that can be critical for you, since it's the first thing that the user sees in your app.

Comment: thanks for your support. I tested DialogFragment but the problem is that when it shows it triggers Keyboard, and it disappears when user clicks on screen, and this unwanted since I want to block any UI action till an event occurs (a message received from background service). So I am open to your suggestion and want to use what is better from performance perspective and UX...

Comment: Well...it's pretty simple. You just need to make a nice fragment that will tell the user what's going on (perhaps a progressbar and some text - there's really no need for much more, except a logo maybe) and after you get the server response, just replace the fragment with your next one.
If you want a suggestion for a nice UX, then there's a simple answer too...make a badass fragment transition with some cool animations. That makes people happy. Also, you need to resolve what to do if there's no internet connection/airplane mode on etc.
I know...it's pretty vague, but essentially, that's it.

Comment: with Fragments I can use only one Activity (MainActivity) right? And create One Fragment for showing some Text till an Event occurs, then delete the First Fragment and show another Fragment on the same Activity.. I hope that I understood right since I am new to Android development. So I will see some beginner example and tell you the Result after testing or if you have one to start with pls tell me.

Comment: Yes and no :D 
When you use Fragments, an Activity is a container for them. So you can reuse them in other activities. But a good thing to know is that Google recommends single-activity apps now as it is reducing possible code multiplication.
To replace those frags, there's already a method **replace()** in **FragmentTransaction** 
Also, as you're new...I would suggest to use Navigation Component from Android Jetpack. It offers pretty good way to create navigation between screens in your app including back stack management. Also, the back button behavior is "solved" there.

Comment: you helped me a lot today. I will see some examples and start testing it on my project then inform you about the result sofar reached. All my regards.

Comment: @ Janeviemus: I implemented 2 fragments (one xml layout file for each Fragment). And created Class that extends "android.app.Fragment" for each Fragment. I tried to delete the old fragment and replace it with new one whe Event occurs but without success. So is it possible to delate old layout made via xml layout and replace it with new one made with xml layout?

Comment: It is working perfectly now. I just have to make it now get data from SharedPreferences. Thanks a  lot Janeviemus